# Upload file on laravel from $request->input()

Tags: angular, laravel

I wanna upload my file to FTP, but i can´t use $request->file("Fichier1") because I'm sending this data from angular by json.

DATA SEND FROM ANGULAR TO LARAVEL
[image: DATA SEND FROM ANGULAR TO LARAVEL]

TRY TO GET THE DATA IN LARAVEL BUT THIS RETURN NULL
[image: Try to get the data but this is null]

Answer (score 0):

The correct way would be to send a multipart form instead of json. This is typically done with a FormData object.

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', this.file);
this.httpClient.post(url, formData)
```

Here's a tutorial: https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-formdata/

However, if you would rather work with json, get the file data from $request->all()  instead of $request->file().

**JSON**

```
{
    "name": "Test.pdf",
    "type": "application/pdf",
    "size": "12100",
    "value": "%PDF-1.6↵%����↵4 0 obj↵<</Linearized 1/L 66229/O 6/E 20381/N 1/T 66030/H
    [ 836 170]>>↵endobj↵                    ↵xref↵4 27↵0000000016 00000 n↵0000001006
    00000 n↵0000001066 00000 n↵0000001531 00000 n↵0000001565 00000 n↵0000002420 
    00000 n↵0000003185 00000 n↵0000003945 00000 n↵0000004352 00000 n↵0000004792 
    ..."
}
```

**Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function store_file(Request $request) {
        $file = $request->all();
        Storage::put("directory/".$file['name'], $file);
    }
}
```

If the json data is not the root of the request, and is in an attribute named something like 'file', use input('file'), instead of all()

```
$file = $request->input('file');
```

Comment: This probably just won't work then. It's better to use the multipart form.